# Returning values these values into multiple columns

Tags: sql

Currently, I am have been screwing around with some SQL stuff to help me with my Power BI reports.

Currently, this is the code I am working with

```
SELECT DISTINCT custf.FieldValue AS ID
FROM CustomFields custf
    INNER JOIN ProjectFields projf 
        ON projf.ProjectFieldId = custf.ProjectFieldId
    INNER JOIN Projects proj 
        ON proj.ProjectId = projf.ProjectId
WHERE proj.TenantId = '130' 
   AND proj.ProjectId='1650' 
   AND projf.Name = 'UnitAmount'
```

However, the way the database is set up seems very, "odd", to me. Because in order for me to return the value for a field I have to reference 2 other tables (as you can see by the statement)

My issue is though I need to return two columns (or more) from the one table BUT the only way to differentiate between the data (Because it is all in the one column) is the name of the field (projf.Name = #Field name I want returned#)

Is it possible to return, for example, the UnitAmount and the InvoiceDate, even though I need to change the WHERE condition?

Any help, feedback or pushes in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can start by telling us what rdbms you are working on, and add to your question the relevant table's DDL and some sample data as DDL, as well as desired results. That way you will increse your chances of getting a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you would want to use the `IN` clause. You will also want to add another field to your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT projf.Name,
    custf.FieldValue AS ID
FROM CustomFields custf
    INNER JOIN ProjectFields projf 
        ON projf.ProjectFieldId = custf.ProjectFieldId
    INNER JOIN Projects proj 
        ON proj.ProjectId = projf.ProjectId
WHERE proj.TenantId = '130' 
    AND proj.ProjectId = '1650' 
    AND projf.Name IN ('UnitAmount', 'InvoiceDate')
```

Comment: Thanks for that response (Sorry for late reply haven't had an internet connection in like 24 hours)

However I need those two or more values to return in different columns as opposed to the the one with a label on them. Any ideas?

Thanks